# R - Shiny Filter for 'All' values

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way to put a filter on a Shiny App, but for Shiny to know that if there is nothing selected to show all the data? For example, using the `ggplot2` `diamonds` data, I've built the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
diamonds <- diamonds

#Unique cut dropdown
cut <- sort(unique(diamonds$cut))

#Unique color
color <- sort(unique(diamonds$color))

#Unique clarity
clarity <- sort(unique(diamonds$clarity))

#Shiny App

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("diamonds"),
  fluidRow(
  column(3,
       selectizeInput("CutSelect", "Cut", cut, selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE),
       br(),
       selectInput("ColorSelect", "Color", color),
       br(),
       selectInput("ClaritySelect", "Clarity", clarity)
),
tableOutput("results")
)
)
server <- function(input, output) {
output$results <- renderTable({
filtered <- 
  diamonds %>%
  filter(cut == input$CutSelect,
         color == input$ColorSelect,
         clarity == input$ClaritySelect)
filtered
})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Which produces an app that looks like this:

[image]

Without cleaning the data, is there a way to add an "All" operator to the filters that will allow the app to know that even though there is a filter for that dimension, that there are instances where "All" would come in handy?

For cut, specifically, if I leave the `selectizeInput` blank, I'd like that to operate as an "All" or "no filter" type deal.

Happy to provide any more information that can be useful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

An empty `selectInput` returns `NULL` so you could do the filtering only if the `selectInput` is not `NULL` (i.e. one or more values have been selected):

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$results <- renderTable({
    filtered <- diamonds
    if (!is.null(input$CutSelect)) {
      filtered <- filtered %>% filter(cut == input$CutSelect)
    }
    if (!is.null(input$ColorSelect)) {
      filtered <- filtered %>% filter(color == input$ColorSelect)
    }
    if (!is.null(input$ClaritySelect)) {
      filtered <- filtered %>% filter(clarity == input$ClaritySelect)
    }
    filtered
  })
}
```

That way if a `selectInput` is empty (`NULL`) no filtering is performed on that dimension.

Comment: This is a great start, thanks, Kristoffer! To take it one step further, what if I had more inputs that were a bit more stagnant and needed a selection to compute? So for example, if I added a numeric input for `carat` that needed an input and would only return `carat >= #`, how could I make that `numericInput` work with what we already have?

Comment: You could use a Shiny [sliderInput](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/sliderInput.html) and then filter on the max and min from that input.

Comment: What would the code for that look like appended to the above? Right now, I'm running into a problem where if I wanted to add another input. that it's not recognizing those filters because of the code ending after the IF statements.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the [DT](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/) when it comes to presenting/filtering data. DT has a builtin *filter* option, which allows you to filter one or several values or range of values in the table. You may put the filter at the top or bottom of the table. Here is the code which meets your objectives:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(DT)
diamonds <- diamonds

#Shiny App

ui <- fluidPage(
           titlePanel("diamonds"),
        fluidRow(
           dataTableOutput("results")
        )
      )
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$results <- DT::renderDataTable(filter='top',{
       diamonds
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Oh, this is interesting! Thanks, Hrant. Is there a way to turn off the filtering for the metrics and only have it for the dimensions? Or, in this instance, does it have to be an all or nothing type deal for column filtering?

Comment: It is not possible to completely hide the filter area from selected columns, yet you can make it inactive by tuning off the searchability as described [here](http://rstudio.github.io/DT/009-searchable.html). The following code will work in your case:
DT::renderDataTable(**options=list(columnDefs = list(list(searchable = FALSE, targets = 5)))**,filter='top',{
       diamonds
    })
where 5 is the column number for which you want to deactivate filtering option.