# Filter a data frame based on a Shiny user input equal to "None Selected" = NA

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

Using Shiny, I am trying to filter a data frame based on user input and then display the filtered data frame. I am struggling to find a strategy that will allow me to, when applicable, not filter the data frame and display the unfiltered data frame. I searched Stack Overflow for help and found  this similar question [R - Shiny Filter for 'All' values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42742788/r-shiny-filter-for-all-values). I tried to implement the solution recommended by Kristoffer Winther Balling but was unsuccessful. When I select the "None Selected" option an empty table is displayed rather than an unfiltered table.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons(inputId = "cut", label = "Select Cut",
                   choiceNames = c(levels(as.factor(diamonds$cut)), "None Selected"),
                   choiceValues = c(levels(as.factor(diamonds$cut)), NA))
    ),
    mainPanel(tableOutput("diamonds_filtered"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$diamonds_filtered <- renderTable({
    diamonds_filtered <- diamonds
    if (!is.na(input$cut)) {
      diamonds_filtered <- filter(diamonds_filtered, cut == input$cut)
    }
    head(diamonds_filtered)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Filtering on a user input not equal to NA works as expected. 
[Proper filtering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAZZ8.png)

Yet when the input is "None Selected" and the value is NA, an unfiltered data frame is not displayed. [improper filtering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3SZT.png)

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong are greatly appreciated.

Comment: use `if (input$cut!="") {...`  instead

Comment: @HubertL thank you very much for your suggestion! Once I modified the value of the "None Selected" option to =  "" and changed my `if` statement as you recommended I got the desired output. Thanks!! I have answered the question below with your suggestion.

Comment: It should work as well if you keep the NA

Answer (score 0):

As recommended by @HubertL in the comments above if I change the value of the "None Selected" option to = "" and changed my if to `f (input$cut!="") {...` i get the desired functionality.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons(inputId = "cut", label = "Select Cut",
                   choiceNames = c(levels(as.factor(diamonds$cut)), "None Selected"),
                   choiceValues = c(levels(as.factor(diamonds$cut)), ""))
    ),
    mainPanel(tableOutput("diamonds_filtered"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$diamonds_filtered <- renderTable({
    diamonds_filtered <- diamonds
    if (input$cut != "")) {
      diamonds_filtered <- filter(diamonds_filtered, cut == input$cut)
    }
    head(diamonds_filtered)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```